# ClassCastException when deserializing multiple objects from ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, serialization, classcastexception

I am having a problem with deserializing multiple objects from an `ObjectInputStream`. I have a class called `GameSave` that can do 3 things: serialize objects and save them to a file, delete a save file, and load objects from a save file. I have another class that handles the GUI and calls the methods in the `GameSave` class. This is where I am getting a `ClassCastException`:

```
p1 = (Player) GameSave.load("Mappy");
p2 = (Player) GameSave.load("Mappy");
p3 = (Player) GameSave.load("Mappy");
p4 = (Player) GameSave.load("Mappy");
map = (ArrayList<Star>) GameSave.load("Mappy"); // I am getting the error on this line
```

This is the code in my `GameSave` class:

```
public class GameSave {

public static void save(String n) {
    File saveFile = new File("saves/" + n + ".sav");
    try {
        FileOutputStream saveOut = new FileOutputStream(saveFile);
        try (ObjectOutputStream saveObj = new ObjectOutputStream(saveOut)) {
            saveObj.writeObject(Test.p1);
            saveObj.writeObject(Test.p2);
            saveObj.writeObject(Test.p3);
            saveObj.writeObject(Test.p4);
            saveObj.writeObject(Test.map);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Test.saveError.setVisible(true);
    }
}

public static void delete(String n) {
    File saveFile = new File("saves/" + n + ".sav");
    saveFile.delete();
}

public static Object load(String n) {
    try {
        FileInputStream saveIn = new FileInputStream("saves/" + n + ".sav");
        try (ObjectInputStream loadObj = new ObjectInputStream(saveIn)) {
            return loadObj.readObject();
        }
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Test.loadError.setVisible(true);
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.santiago.spacegame.src.Player cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
at com.santiago.spacegame.src.Test.initComponents(Test.java:47)
at com.santiago.spacegame.src.Test.<init>(Test.java:23)
at com.santiago.spacegame.src.Test.lambda$main$1(Test.java:69)
at com.santiago.spacegame.src.Test$$Lambda$1/1159190947.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I am getting this error even though the objects are loaded in the same order as they were saved. I made sure that all objects that are being saved through `GameSave` implement `Serializable`. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I tried loading the save like this, by only calling the `load` method once:

```
Object load = GameSave.load("Mappy");
p1 = (Player) load;
p2 = (Player) load;
p3 = (Player) load;
p4 = (Player) load;
map = (ArrayList<Star>) load;
```

but it still gives me a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Your write method writes everything to the same stream - this is good. Your read method opens a stream each time - this means you read the same object, the first one, every time. Hence when you try and read this into a `List` you get an error.

Comment: Show us your class Test. Btw, it seems your object map is of ArrayList type, and you are trying to cast it to Player.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, aha, I see what you mean. Would I have to make a new instance of an `Object` in my class `Test` (the GUI class) and then cast that to my specific types?

Comment: I don't think you do see what I mean. You need to rethink your `load` method as it is wrong.

Comment: Can you show me what is going wrong?

Comment: What does `load` do? What happens when you call it twice? Why would calling it more than one result in a different object being read?

Comment: I modified my code so that `load` is only called once, but it's still not working.

Comment: What do you think your change does? Please use a debugger and step through the code to see what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After figuring some things out, I am able to answer my own question. As Boris the Spider mentioned, I am opening a new stream each time I read the file, so this always returns the first object, a `Player`. So, to fix this, I changed my load method to a void instead of returning an `Object` for `Test` to handle. The method now looks like this:

```
public static void load(String n) {
    try {
        FileInputStream saveIn = new FileInputStream("saves/" + n + ".sav");
        try (ObjectInputStream loadObj = new ObjectInputStream(saveIn)) {
            Test.p1 = (Player) loadObj.readObject();
            Test.p2 = (Player) loadObj.readObject();
            Test.p3 = (Player) loadObj.readObject();
            Test.p4 = (Player) loadObj.readObject();
            Test.map = (ArrayList<Star>) loadObj.readObject();
        }
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Test.loadError.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

In `Test`, all I have to do to load the save is this:

```
GameSave.load(nameOfSave);
```

instead of having to set each individual variable.